# dynamo db many to many to many relationships

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, data-modeling

I have a db design that requires a many 2 many 2 many.

- ObjectA can have multiples of ObjectB
- ObjectB can have multiples of ObjectC
- ObjectB can have multiples of ObjectD
- ObjectC can have multiples of ObjectE
- ObjectB can have multiples of ObjectE

I dug up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50205518/dynamodb-m-m-adjacency-list-design-pattern/50238513#50238513) post about adjacent lists.
It makes sense for the simpler model they are dealing with.

The other thing I should add is I don't want to duplicate data. For instance I am storing addresses in ObjectB, I want those to be unique. I was thinking of just Base64 encoding the entire address line and using that for hash key.

I have two questions:

1. is dynamo the correct database to use for this?
2. What would the data model look like in dynamo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer to you question is actually in the question itself. You want to have many to many **relationships** in a NoSQL (non relational)  DB. Despite being able to achieve your goal with Dynamo, this will implicate a lot of unnecessary problems. I suggest you change the direction and go with RDS, the SQL Service of AWS.

Comment: That is a fair point and is what i was thinking. The only draw back I can think of is I am using lambda, and at scale is connection limit to RDS.

But thank you for the response.

Comment: There are workarounds to this. You can search a bit on the matter and you will find a lot of information. Simply put, you can achieve connection pooling by creating connections out of the handler scope. Check this https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=216000

Comment: I was able to get this easily working in SQL. Thanks for the advice.